# Configure a proxy to make a request or run a test on Runscope

Tags: proxy, request, travis-ci, runscope

I have not been able to find if there is a way to configure a proxy on Runscope (or using runscope-radar). This is exactly my problem:

I want to make a test with this flow:

1. make a request to our API and save some data
2. make a request to an **external API** and save some data
3. make another request to our API

To be able to make a request to the external API I am using a proxy (I can execute it with Postman and see the response). 
It is important to mention that this test is going to be run in our CI pipeline too, which is using TravisCI, so the solution has to be ***generic*** just to be able to be executed in other machines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The agent will use the proxy settings set in the HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY environment variables. It's not possible to configure a proxy otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I was absolutely wrong, but I feel like someone googling might happen upon this thread and this could be helpful.

All credit goes to John for his useful comment. Stringing together multiple requests does exist in runscope:

https://www.runscope.com/docs/api-testing

Comment: Stringing requests together is a core feature of API tests. Variables let you pass data between the requests. https://www.runscope.com/docs/api-testing https://www.runscope.com/docs/api-testing/variables